# Filling in the blanks with single table select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table:

```
table1:

user_id | date_created | product
1         2020-10-02     1
1         2020-10-08     1
1         2020-10-08     1
1         2020-10-09     1
```

And the select:

```
select to_char(date_created, 'Dy') as day,
    count(product)
from table1
where user_id = 1
    and date_created >= now() - interval '10 days'
group by day
```

It produces the following output:

```
 day | count
-----+-------
 Fri |     1
 Thu |     2
 Fri |     1
(3 rows)
```

How can I fill in the blanks for the days where no `products` exist so they show `0`?  Something like this:

```
day  | count
-----+-------
 Fri |     1
 Sat |     0
 Sun |     0
 Mon |     0
 Tue |     0
 Wed |     0
 Thu |     2
 Fri |     1
(8 rows)
```

Joining two tables with a `left outer` join would work, but I'm working with a single table here.  I *could* fudge it on the frontend, but it would be nice to be able to take care of this in SQL.

I'd appreciate comments!

thanks

Comment: Create a temp table with all the days you want, then left join on your table and join on day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
select to_char(d.dt, 'Dy') as day,
       count(t.product)
from generate_series(current_date - 10, current_date, interval '1 day') as d(dt)
  left join table1 t 
         on t.user_id = 1 
        and t.date_created = d.dt::date
group by day
```